# Mnogodb поиск в коллекции по запросу

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

К примеру у меня в коллекции items хранятся товары, как получить все или конкретный товар у меня нет проблем, но допустим я делаю поиск по имени, и пользователь ввел в поиск неполное имя товара, к примеру "ло", так же в коллекции хранятся товары с именами "лосось", "лом" и он должен их получить. Не нашел примера, где есть поиск с неполным именем товара, то есть должен вернуть товары по совпадению символов в данном случае. Я могу предположить, что надо использовать регулярные выражения.

Comment: `db.items.find({name : /ло/)})`

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.

Comment: А могу я как нибудь поместить в такие символы переменную  /переменная/ ?

Comment: `{name : new RegExp(переменная)}`

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать 